# opening Omnet from ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, omnet++

I am new to Omnet++. I installed Omnetpp-3.3p1 and am having trouble opening it. I tried creating a makefile within the project which has simulation codes with command `opp_makemake -f -N`, but I am getting `command opp_makemake` not found error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check Pages 11 to 19 in [Omnet++ Installation Guide](http://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf) and make sure you have followed all the steps. It also needs a lot of packages to be installed for support.

Comment: This documentation is for version 4.2.2 I need one with version 3.3p1. I figured out that the installation for the versions are different!

Comment: @SadikshaGautam: Which compiler are you using? Which version? There is OMNeT++ 3.3p2 patch, that applies to OMNeT++ 3.3p1 and contains fixes for GCC 4.4. I remember that I was able to compile the sources by using this patch.

Comment: @enzom83: I was installing Omnet-3.3p1 in ubuntu 11.10. I had previously installed omnet 4.2 without any problem but due to academic reasons I had to go down to 3.3p1.

Comment: @SadikshaGautam: Try to apply the patch.

Answer (score 2):

The error might raise if OMNeT++ is not properly installed or the lib is not properly linked. This [PDF](http://uhost.rmutp.ac.th/tanavoot.n/Paper_References/WorkShop_Omnet/Document_Omnet/Castalia%20-%20Installation.pdf) should be what you are looking for, since it explains how to properly install version 3.3p1. - Hope to help!

Comment: Actually I was having problem with "make" in omnet. It was giving me error with filetokenizer.cc. I had to add "#include <stdio.h>" in that file. Anyways thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Ok, glad you have fixed your problem. Next time try to be even more specific! People might answer way faster than I did, with a better answer. :)

Comment: @SadikshaGautam Oh and please next time try to be more specific with your question. I don't see where was mentioned the filetokenizer.cc error. Regards

Comment: I didn't know that the error was caused because of filetokenizer.cc. So it is not mentioned in the question. I had to figure out on my own!